# startActivityforResult from adapter

Tags: android, adapter, startactivityforresult

I have an adapter inside a fragment, in this adapter I am running an `activityForResult` to an activity.

Calling the adapter from the Fragment

```
mAdapClinicSchedule = new ClinicScheduleAdapter(getContext(),mScheduleList);
                               mLvClinicsSchedules.setAdapter(mAdapClinicSchedule);
```

Adapter's constructor:

```
public ClinicScheduleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mScheduleList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mScheduleList = mScheduleList;
    }
```

The call to the `startActivityForResult` from the adapter

```
case R.id.tvDaysClinicSchedule:

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScheduleDaysActivity.class);
                ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                break;
```

The `setResult` from the activity

```
case R.id.tvSelectDays:

                checkDaysSelected();
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("monday", mondaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("tuesday", tuesdaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("wednesday", wednesdaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("thursday", thursdaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("friday", fridaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("saturday", saturdaySelected);
                returnIntent.putExtra("sunday", sundaySelected);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                break;
```

Creating an `onActivityResult` interface

```
public interface OnActivityResult {

    void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

That implements the adapter:

```
public class ClinicScheduleAdapter 
       extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener, OnActivityResult { ... }
```

In the fragment it overrite the `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        mAdapClinicSchedule.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

But in the adapter, it does not show the toast, I do not know what I can be doing wrong

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 2) {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "it worked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your `Activity.onActivityResult()` being called when you return from the second activity?

Comment: so i have to call activity.onActivityResult in the activity that contains the fragment?

Comment: No - it should be called by the OS. You should double check it does, otherwise, it means you did something wrong.

Comment: I perform the test in the override onActivityResult method of the fragment and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html):

> Of course, the activity that responds must be designed to return a result. When it does, it sends the result as another Intent object. Your activity receives it in the onActivityResult() callback.

Although, if I remember correctly, `onActivityResult()` will get called on whatever started the activity for result. So if you use the activity to start your new intent, then the activity will receive the result call. This means if you want the fragment to handle it, you'll need to call `startActivityForResult(...)` on the fragment rather than the activity

[fragment source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

Comment: but the startActivityForResult I'm calling from the adapter

Comment: From the adapter, you're calling `((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);`

If you want the fragment to resolve the result, you have to do `fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, 2);`

Comment: Or, if you don't have access to the fragment in your adapter, you will have to instead override `onActivityResult()` in your activity (whatever context is getting called `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: if I want to use the fragment, I declare it in the adapter's constructor, but how do I pass the fragment instance to the adapter's constructor

Comment: You could either pass the fragment in to the adapters constructor or have a method to set the fragment.

So to pass into the constructor:
`mAdapClinicSchedule = new ClinicScheduleAdapter(this,mScheduleList);`

You will then need to store a reference to the fragment. You'll want to be careful about leaking the fragment here though.

Comment: but try with the this in the call to the adapater constructor in the fragment and it gives me error.

Comment: What is the error? Have you made sure to change the adapters constructor to take a fragment as the parameter instead of the context?

Comment: public ClinicScheduleAdapter(Fragment fragment, ArrayList<String> mScheduleList) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.mScheduleList = mScheduleList;
    }

Comment: yes, I put the constructor as you say it and generates an error when placing the this

Comment: Well, you could go back to passing the activity in the constructor. Then you could always create a new method on your adapter `public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) { this.fragment = fragment }`, then call that immediately after the constructor call. You will need to then use the `fragment` that you store when you want to launch the activity by doing: `this.fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, 2)`.